# How to use compile messages in django?

Tags: python

How can I use --ignore in makemessages?
e.g.
My try is to do this

```
Python manage.py makemessages --ignore=venv/*
```

But it's showing errors.
Error says no match.
what is the proper approach for this?

Comment: Have you set the locale path location in settings? ` LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"), )`

Comment: please mention that you are asking about Django framework and not general python